# Clear validation message only for the control as soon the user enters a value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I need to clear validation message for the text box as soon as the user enters some charectors into the text box. I need to do the same for the combobox, As soon as the user selects a dropdown valuie the error message should clear

How can it be handled using jquery

```
$('#ProjectContent').keypress(function () {
        resetValidation();

    });



    function resetValidation() {



    }
```

textbox

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectContent, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ProjectContent, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", cols = "50" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectContent, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Combobox

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.CountryCode)
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                        .DataTextField("CompanyCodeCompany")
                        .DataValueField("CountryCode")
                        .Filter("contains")
                        .MinLength(3)
                        .Events(e => e.DataBound("onCompanyComboChange"))
                        .Value(@user.DefaultCountryCode)
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Read(read => read.Action("RequestHeader_SalesOrganisation", "Request").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
                        .ServerFiltering(true)
                        )
                        )
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What do you want to "clear" validation message: just hide or remove it completely from view? The simplest way is to just hide that message using jQuery: `$('.text-danger').hide();` or `$('.field-validation-error').hide();`. If you want to clear message using CSS class, use `$('.text-danger').removeClass('.text-danger')` or `$('.field-validation-error').removeClass('field-validation-error');`

Comment: This will clear all on the screen. Need to do it for specific contol as soon as the user enters a valid valiue

Comment: You can wrap `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` in a `div` with `id` attribute then use it to hide message after user input, e.g. `$("#validationmessagediv").hide();`. What do you mean "clear all on the screen" then?

Comment: I mean hide that validation message. If I call $('.text-danger').hide(); or $('.text-danger').removeClass('.text-danger') It will hide for all controls. Which event do I need to call these for the controls. I have textarea, textbox and kendo combox controls

Comment: If it is the case, then you may want to wrap `ValidationMessageFor` in an HTML `div` element and hide it like I had explained in third comment. May you want something different other than using `div` wrapper for target `ValidationMessageFor` to hide it?

Comment: My question is also regarding the event of the controls ? It will be great if you can show me an example

Comment: How about this to bind with `ComboBoxFor`: `$("#CountryCode").data("kendoComboBox").input.keypress(function() { resetValidation(); });`? I assumed that combobox name is same as model name assigned on it.

Comment: I had added detailed explanation about possible things what you want to hide validation messages based from comments above, let me know how you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a `TextAreaFor` and Kendo `ComboBoxFor` with `ValidationMessageFor` wrapped inside HTML `div` elements like this example:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ProjectContent, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", cols = "50" }})
    <div id="message1">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProjectContent, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<!-- other stuff -->

<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.CountryCode)
    .Name("CountryCode")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    .DataTextField("CompanyCodeCompany")
    .DataValueField("CountryCode")
    .Filter("contains")
    .MinLength(3)
    .Events(e => e.DataBound("onCompanyComboChange"))
    .Value(@user.DefaultCountryCode)
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Read(read => read.Action("RequestHeader_SalesOrganisation", "Request").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
    .ServerFiltering(true)
    ))
</div>
<div id="message2">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

To hide validation message corresponding to `ComboBoxFor` individually, you can use `id` name of the `div` to hide it when doing [`keypress`](http://www.telerik.com/forums/keypress-event-for-combobox):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#CountryCode').data('kendoComboBox').input.keypress(function() {
         resetComboValidation(); 
    });

    function resetComboValidation() {
        $("#message2").hide();
    }
});
```

Additionally, you can hide multiple validation messages wrapped in div elements which have `id` attribute value starts with `message` (or whatever name you've assigned for them) using jQuery [`attributeStartsWith` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // TextAreaFor
    $('#ProjectContent').keypress(function() {
        resetValidation();
    });

    // ComboBoxFor
    $('#CountryCode').data('kendoComboBox').input.keypress(function() {
        resetValidation(); 
    });

    // hide validation messages
    function resetValidation() {
        $('div[id^="message"]').hide();
    }
});
```

NB: `attributeStartsWith` selector also apply for all `div` elements using same name, i.e. `<div id="message">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(...)</div>` to wrap all `ValidationMessageFor` should work. Also, `keypress` event used by `ComboBoxFor` can be substituted by `bind` containing `keypress` like this:

```
$('#CountryCode').data('kendoComboBox').input.bind({
    keypress: function() { 
        resetValidation(); 
    }
});
```

Reference:

[kendo.ui.ComboBox JavaScript API (jQuery)](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to specify name/id html attribute in your text area/combobox to execute keypress event.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ProjectContent, new { htmlAttributes = new { @name="ProjectContent",@class = "form-control", cols = "50" }})
```

If it still not work write event inline as below

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ProjectContent, new { htmlAttributes = new { @name="ProjectContent",@class = "form-control", cols = "50" , keypress="yourMethod()"}})
```